# how can i Take snapshots of my Android application/Layout

Tags: android

i am created an application in android.In that i have a doubt,for explaining that i have to show the graphical layout of main.xml. it is possible to copy my code and paste here so that everybody can see the code.Now i want to display my graphical layout along with my code.Is it possible?? if it is possible means how?

Comment: use some basic html <img src="" width="">

Comment: can you understand me...i want to display the eclipse emulator ...that is not an image..then  how can i use the html tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to capture the photos of your application
running inside the emulator.

For taking screen shots of your application, follow the below steps:

1. click on Window menu -> DDMS
2. Click on "Devices" icon lying at the left-bottom corner.
3. It will list out all the devices, select the device from which you want to take screen shots.
4. click on "Screen capture" button.